# Load all values from xml into list of tuple

Tags: c#, xml, linq

In my xml each record tag have two elements like `id1` and `id2`

I want to load `id1` and `id2` of all the records and save all `id1` in `item1` and all `id2` in `item2` in the list of tuples

I want something like this

```
var tuples = doc.Root.Descendants("record").Select(p => new 
Tuple<int,int>(p.Element("id1").Value,p.Element("id2").Value));
```

But this is applicable for only one object of tuple but I want to save in 
list of integer tuples

Comment: ``But this is applicable for only Tuple but I want to save in List>`` - whats that supposed to mean?

Comment: sorry missed some text actually the above logic is only for one tuple object I want to save in list of integer tuples.

Comment: Can you share an example XML?

Comment: I believe your `var tuples` will be of type `IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>>` in which case you can just append `.ToList()` at the end to capture the results in a list.

Comment: <Record><id1>1</id1><id2>11</id2></Record>

Comment: how many records do you have with the name "Record"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following XML:

```
var xmlStr = "<records><record><id1>1</id1><id2>1</id2></record><record><id1>1</id1><id2>2</id2></record><record><id1>3</id1><id2>3</id2></record></records>";
```

Your posted code should work fine, the only thing thats missing is that you don't parse the string of `.Value` to `int`.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
var tuples = xDoc.Root.Descendants("record").Select(x => new Tuple<int, int>(int.Parse(x.Element("id1").Value), int.Parse(x.Element("id2").Value))).ToList();
```

As suggested in the comments I included `.ToList()`, to make a `List<Tuple<int, int>>` instead of `IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>>`.

Comment: got it i was actually getting confused.Thank you

Comment: @Remon No problem.